# Iterating through array javascript google maps markers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

**Background to Question**

I have an array which includes latitude and longitude values. I have the below code which places a marker for each iteration. I am using a Ruby gem Gon to pass values from the database to javascript. The below is working as expected:

```
function populateMap(map){
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < gon.length; ++index) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.murals[index].lat, gon.murals[index].long);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map  
      }); 
    }
  }
```

However I want to have an info window for each marker with the address. This is done by reverse geo-coding. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.

The below code works for reverse geocoding 1 marker:

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.murals[0].lat, gon.murals[0].long);
      geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[1]) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address ;
            });           
          } else {
              window.alert('No results found'); 
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
      }); 
  }
```

**Actual Question**
When I add the for loop to the reverse geo0code function it only places the marker of the last iteration.

```
   function populateMapTest(map, geocoder, infowindow){
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < gon.murals.length; ++index) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.murals[index].lat, gon.murals[index].long);
      alert("start of iteration: " + index);
      geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status){
        alert("middle of iteration: " + index);
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[1]) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address ;

            });

          } else {
              window.alert('No results found'); 
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }

      });

      alert("end of iteration: " + index);
    }  
  }
```

For each iteration the alerts are in the following order: Start of iteration, end of iteration, middle of iteration. It seems to be skipping over the code contained in the geocoder brackets till all the iterations are done. I think?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: geocoder.geocode seems async, so the middle iteration seems likely to always run at the end (e.g. after "end-of-iteration").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem like a closure issue. But I think it could be because of the variable `latlng` instead of the index, (or both).

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.murals[index].lat, gon.murals[index].long);
```

The `latlng` above is updated throughout the loop but eventually the function uses only the last iteration's `latlng`. The variables inside the closure (the "middle" function) are referenced and will **all** be updated to the last value when the function actually executes. (I guess a different way of thinking about it, is that it really only looks at the value during execution instead of declaration)

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
```

And at the end, the marker would just be created at the same position, `index` times.

---

As an example, the code below will print ten 9s even if you expect it to print an increasing `x`

```
function foo() {
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; ++index) {
    var x = index;
    setTimeout(function bar() {
      console.log(x)
    }, 10)
  }
}
foo()
```

But this will print it correctly if it was immediately invoked (but of course, this isn't an option for your case)

```
function foo() {
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; ++index) {
    var x = index;
    setTimeout(function bar() {
      console.log(x)
    }(), 10)
  }
}
foo()
```

---

You could move the latlng declaration inside the middle function. (Do check the value of the index too though, because that suffers the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a class closure problem, which relates to the scope of a variable that is declared in a high scope but used in functions that are in a lower scope and persist longer than the higher scope where the variable was actually declared.

Change:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < gon.murals.length; ++index) {
```

to:

```
for (let index = 0; index < gon.murals.length; ++index) {
```

This will give `index` block level scope and each iteration of the loop will have its own value for `index`. Instead of all iterations of the loop sharing the same `index` value, each will get its own.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it has exact same behaviour as the way I had it. Its going thorugh each iteration and then at the very end its doing the 'middle" part.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, (function(indexCopy){
  return function(results, status) {
    alert("middle of iteration: " + indexCopy);
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[1]) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[1].formatted_address ;
        });

      } else {
        window.alert('No results found'); 
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }

  };
})(index));
```

Just a thought...